# Setting multidemensional POST array with variable

Tags: php, post, multidimensional-array

I understand how to set POST variables (`$_POST['u'] = 10`), and I understand how to call a multi-demensional post value (`$_POST['u']['number2']`), so to set a simple multi-demensional POST, it'd be simple (`$_POST['u']['number2'] = 10`).

The problem comes when I need to set a POST variable by use of a variable, i.e., `$_POST['u']['$number'] = $number2`, where `$number` is a string from a loop.

What's going on is the loop takes data from the POST[u][$number], manipulates it, spits out $number2, and I'm wanting to update the POST[u][$number] with $number2, if that makes any sense.

So, basically, is there anyway for me to do `$_POST['u']['$number'] = $number2`?

I tried using `eval` but that didn't work...

Comment: Single quotes parse literal strings!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you mean:

```
$_POST['u'][$number] = $number2;
```

Without single quote. Or even:

```
$_POST['u']["{$number}"] = $number2; //> Discouraged
```